# Ordering lost when returning self.get_queryset() in GET method of ListAPIView in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use the `ordering_fields` with a `ListAPIView` in Django REST Framework. When I override the `get` method to return self.get_queryset(), ordering is lost.

How can I maintain the ordering specified in the `ORDERING_PARAM`s from the url (`ordering`) while returning the `ListAPIView`'s `self.get_queryset()`?

I am aware of less elegant solutions where I can grab the ordering fields from the url using:

```
ordering_params = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get(
    'ordering', None
)

ordering_params_list = ordering_params.split(',')

# some other code to remove invalid fields not in `ordering_fields` ...
```

But I'd like to use Django REST Framework to maintain the `ordering_fields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually

`get_queryset` just to return the dataset without **filter**.

`filter_queryset`: it will handle the `ordering_fields`, `search_fields`, `filter_fields`..

default `list` method will get the queryset like this:

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

If you don't want to call filter_queryset, You can call the `orderingFilter` by yourself.

```
from rest_framework import filters
queryset = filters.OrderingFilter().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the ordering of queryset, you need to wrap it with `filter_queryset` method:

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```